# Mongodb query exceptionally slow

Tags: mongodb

My mongodb is rather simple: a dataset/entry has around 30 properties on 3 layers. One such entry has up to around 5000 characters. I have 500k of them.
When I execute the following query...

```
db.images.find({ "featureData.cedd": { $exists: false}}).count()
```

...it is extremely slow. It's not indexed, but still.. from my MySQL experience it shouldn't take **20 minutes** to execute one such query.

While being executed (directly on the mongo terminal) there's 3% CPU usage and still over 2 Gigs of free memory.

Thanks for giving me a hint on what I could do!

EDIT: An explain() of the query (without count) gives:

```
db.images.find({ "featureData.cedd": { $exists: false }}).explain()
{
    "cursor" : "BasicCursor",
    "nscanned" : 532537,
    "nscannedObjects" : 532537,
    "n" : 438,
    "millis" : 1170403,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "indexBounds" : {

    }
}
```

Output of iostat:

```
Linux 3.2.0-58-generic (campartex)      03/25/2014      _x86_64_        (2 CPU)

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
          34.93    0.01    0.25    0.48    0.00   64.33

Device:            tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn
sda               2.08       103.79        11.26  172805914   18749067
fd0               0.00         0.00         0.00        148          0
```

Output of explain() **after adding an index**:

```
db.images.find({ "featureData.cedd": { $exists: false }}).explain()
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor featureData.cedd_1",
    "nscanned" : 438,
    "nscannedObjects" : 438,
    "n" : 438,
    "millis" : 2,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "isMultiKey" : true,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "indexBounds" : {
            "featureData.cedd" : [
                    [
                            null,
                            null
                    ]
            ]
    }
}
```

Comment: `explain`ing the query is always a good first step

Comment: Btw please consider before writing stuff like "for counting mongo has to go through all tupels" that we're talking about 15 minutes here for only half a million records.. :)

Comment: I could only find an "explain()", no describe. And that "explain" runs for 1 minute now x/ Same low CPU and memory usage

Comment: explain() hasn't terminated yet. I'll write here once it has ^^

Comment: Done, I added the explain() result. Besides for it taking long, can you read anything out of it?

Comment: Without an index, it has to search _unstructured_ documents for a property existing. On a single node, that's always going to be slower than MySQL searching unindexed but _structured_ data. Try adding an index on `featureData.cedd`.

Comment: Undoubtedly this query is faster with an index. But does this also explain why only 3% of the CPU is used and why it takes 19 minutes (according to posted explain()) to execute the statement without an index?

Comment: Disk IO limited probably. What does iostat say?

Comment: Added iostat output as edit. Doesn't look too busy :S

Comment: Adding an Index brought it from 20 minutes to 2 miliseconds! wtf! I added the new explain() as edit to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case adding an index improved the query speed by a factor of 600'000. `$exists:false` looks for null values - that only works efficiently if the other objects don't have `cedd:null` very often (as a valid value). That is the case here. Further, the objects that have no cedd value are a lot smaller.

Answer (score 6):

TL;DR: Reverse the logic: add a sparse index on a new field `has_cedd` that is either null or some constant (low selectivity index, not ideal, but improved through sparse), or better yet, keep a global counter somewhere else that is updated on every write operation.

Indexing `featureData.cedd` sounds like a bad idea if it can contain up to 5k chars, because that is well beyond the maximum index size and apparently you're not interested in the data itself, only whether it's present.

Oh, and why is this slow? Probably to keep ad-hoc requests fast. MongoDB could dedicate all the resources to this OLAP-like query, but that would introduce lag on any 'regular OLTP-style queries'.

---

There are two problems here:

1. `$exists : false` is evil, and I doubt indexing will help: Indexes are made for *data*, while `$exists` is a 'meta-query' on the structure. It can use an index if there is one on the field and the query is `$exists : true`, because if an indexed value exists, the field itself must also exist on a given document. Reversing that logic is tricky: if the field doesn't exist, it's not in the index or it has super low selectivity. 'Turning around' indexes is generally problematic, that is also true for queries using `$ne` by the way.
2. MongoDB will have to de-serialize 500k objects and inspect each one to perform the `$exists`. You can't compare this to MySQL where you have a fixed table structure, in fact, `$exists : false` doesn't have a SQL-equivalent, because the field MUST exist, otherwise your table is badly broken.

Comment: Thanks for explaining! Still I'm wondering though why only 3% CPU is used for the OLAP query? Can I somehow increase that? Since nothing else is running on the DB that would be quite the waste of resources...

Comment: MAYDAY adding an index brought it from 20 minutes to 2 Miliseconds! wtf! I added the new explain() as edit to the question

Comment: Sooo I guess the index created a seperate list of those which do not have such a feature to index, and therefore the search only has to scan through the exact amount of results, 438 in this case?

Comment: ah, interesting. `$exists:false` looks for null values - that only works efficiently if the other objects don't have `cedd:null` very often (as a valid value), but that seems to be the case. Those objects are probably a lot smaller because the `cedd` field is so large, correct? Otherwise, the query should be faster 'only' by a factor of thousand. What data type do you use as a primary key?

Comment: int. But I don't query by id in this case, just to say. But yes, those without the cedd features tend to be a lot smaller. I'm surprised about the factor too, it improved by a factor of 600'000 ^^

Comment: Would you like to edit your post with the new information so that I can accept it as answer?

Comment: Seems my answer is broken beyond repair, maybe you should post an answer yourself, I'd pretty much have to revert myself...